# Using JMS to persist data in Grails

Tags: grails, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have JMS plugin installed in Grails 2.2.0.  It works famously.  However, I now want to extend the functionality to all my domain objects to persist them across a JMS ActiveMQ connection.

The database is on the remote system which has an `ActiveMQ` broker on it. I can talk to it fine. But, I'm unclear on how to implement the code to `save()`, `search()`, `update()`, etc from my controller using JMS rather than a local DB.  I think I have `save()` figured out but not for sure.  Then how do I hook into the dynamic finders and such to supply the needed service so the actual search criteria is sent over a queue and the response is sent back on another queue and populates the correct Grails results for display?  My head hurts from reading so much and getting no where fast.

Thanks,

Marshall

Comment: So, you mean you cannot do a `JNDI` lookup to the remote database instead you have to use its `ActiveMQ` broker?

Comment: Correct.  All DB activities are to be done by our middleware and the way the Grails front end talks to the middleware is via ActiveMQ.

Comment: Ok. Are you using grails in the middleware as well?